# React Native: Missing xcworkspace

Tags: reactjs, xcode

I created a new project at version 0.70 or earlier 0.68.2 but there is no xcworkspace file and podfile.lock, so how can I open Xcode and edit it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl353.png)

Comment: Have you tried ```npx react-native run-ios```

Answer (score 0):

install pod in the iOS directory it will create missing files

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by running the below command in the project root directory

```
npx pod-install ios
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).